# javascript/html: How do I change onclick=location.herf using document.getElementById

Tags: onclick, href

Am struggling with proper syntax to change a link you go to onclick using javascript.

I have:

js:

```
function changeLink {
link = "page2.php";
document.getElementById('go').onclick= function() { location.href(link); };
}
```

html:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit1" style="width:100%;height:30px" onclick="changeLink();">Change Place To Go</button>
<div id="go" onclick="document.location.href='page1.php';">Click to go somewhere</div>
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZknt/)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some `common.js`:

```
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
var IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
bod.className = 'js';
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version){
    bod.className = className;
  }
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
//]]>
```

Now let's do your main page, `index.php`:

```
//<![CDATA[
function direct(id, link){
  E(id).onclick = function(){
    location = link;
  }
}
direct('button1', 'page1.php'); direct('button2', 'page1.php');
//]]>
```

HTML can look more like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      @import 'common.css'; @import 'index.css';
    </style>
  </head>
<body class='njs'>
  <div id='main'>
    <input type='button' id='button1' value='button 1' />
    <input type='button' id='button2' value='button 2' />
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='index.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your CSS on `common.css`:

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
#main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

Your CSS on `index.css`:

```
#button1,#button2{
  height:30px; width:300px;
}
```

Note:

You could use a CSS `class` instead of the comma separated `id`s. This is just to show you what the syntax should look like. You should know that `onclick` fires before form submission, therefore redirecting would happen before submission, so there is no point in using a `submit` button. There is really no point in having a form in your case, unless you can explain why. I would just use `<a href='page1.php'>page 1</a>`, and the like, so you don't even need to use JavaScript. You can use CSS to style a link into a button.

Comment: where would I write this?